# Splunk: How to add cells of two tables

Tags: splunk

I have multiple tables, can I add/OR/AND... on each cell of all the tables?

For example, if I have below two tables, and add the corresponding cells,

file1.csv

```
row_id,0,2,4
0,     0,1,1
2,     0,0,1
```

file2.csv

```
row_id,0,2,4
0,     0,1,1
2,     0,1,0
```

The expected output is:

```
row_id,0,2,4
0,     0,2,2
2,     0,1,1
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should add the value of cells for the 2 tables:

```
| inputlookup file1.csv
| inputlookup append=t file2.csv
| stats sum(column1), sum(column2) by row_id
```

The first line outputs the content of the first csv file. The append=t in the next line makes sure that the contents of the second csv file are appended at the end of the first.

Assuming row_id as the primary key, we can then sum the values of different columns using the Splunk [stats](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/6.6.3/SearchReference/Stats) command.

Comment: Can you please add some explanation around your answer, rather than just pasting code.  And when you say "Try", it seems that you are suggesting that this is not an answer that will absolutely solve the question, so if you're sure it is then suggest using a more passive language.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @LordWilmore. Edited the same.